# I keep getting the error unkown option -style trying to change background color of gui with tkinter in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttkwidgets

Firstly im a complete beginner in coding in general. Currently im trying to code a gui which allows to download yt videos.

Im trying to change the background color of this gui to blue but I keep getting the error "unkown option "-style""

Comment: Could you please show your code in order for us to see what's wrong?

Comment: Are you using ttk or tk widgets?